# How to stop displaying black screen in android?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am using `Xamarin.Forms` cross platforms. My first screen is splash screen. Then tabbed page. The issue is after splash screen android devices display black screen for 2 to 4 seconds and then Tabbed page is displayed. I am facing issue for Android devices only in OS 7 and later. I am using marshmallow and it works fine. Any Idea about this? Why this is happening in OS version Nougat and more?

Comment: How are you loading the SplashScreen? That black screen, is also related to the loading of packages and assemblies. Have you tried to enable AOT, LLVM, and run in tasks any initializations?

Comment: No. How can I enable this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use AOT and LLVM to improve startup performance, in your AndroidProject.csproj add this under Release:

```
 <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Release</OutputPath>
    <AndroidManagedSymbols>true</AndroidManagedSymbols>
    <AndroidUseSharedRuntime>false</AndroidUseSharedRuntime>
    <AndroidCreatePackagePerAbi>true</AndroidCreatePackagePerAbi>
    <AotAssemblies>true</AotAssemblies>
    <EnableLLVM>true</EnableLLVM>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: Thanks. I have tried and it solved my problem. But it has increased my APK size. Is that possible?

Comment: Yes, the problem of using AOT, is that the size of the APK increases. However you get gains regarding performance. It is a matter of choosing what is more important.

Comment: Okay. Thanks. Actually I don't know about AOT? what is AOT? Any reference link?

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick response.